# Bower ASP.NET Core MVC missing jquery.validate.js file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, jquery-validate, bower, asp.net-core-mvc

UPDATE:
Visual Studio - File - New - Project
- ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) - Web Application

I left the default name **WebApplication1**

- expand the **wwwroot** folder
- expand up to wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation
- in the jquery-validation folder we can see this (see img below)

  [image: jquery-validation folder BEFORE UPDATE]

- right click the **WebApplication1** project in the **src** folder
- click on Manage Bower Packages
- Bower Package Manager screen asking to update **jquery** and **jquery-validation** (see img below)

[image: BowerPackageManager BEFORE UPDATE]

- clicked Update jquery
  **everything looks normal (see img below)

  [image: BowerPackageManager after jquery update]
- clicked Update jquery-validation
  **dist folder has disappeared** (see img below)

  [image]

[image: jquery-validation AFTER UPDATE]

*The text below is before I UPDATED this Q*

I created an empty ASP.NET Core MVC web application in VS2015CE.
I added the bower.json file, that manages client-side stuff of the app.
Via Bower I downloaded jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-validate-unobtrusive.

Bower created a **lib** folder in the **wwwroot** folder.
Somewhere in the ~/lib/jquery-validate/ I should be able to find jquery.validate.js and it's "child" - the jquery.validate.min.js
There were no such files there, so I became suspicious and I created another project, this time a NOT empty web application.

I then compared both **jquery-validate** folders in the **lib** folders of the two applications.

- My first project (created as EMPTY) has the following folder
  structure:

[image]

**dist folder is not present**

- My second project (created as WebApplication, NOT empty) has the
  following folder structure:

[image]

**dist folder is present** and inside it there's the jquery.validate.js file and also it's child, the jquery.validate.min.js file.

**What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in VS2015? Or a Bower bug?**

Comment: FYI:  `jquery.validate.min.js` is not the "child" of `jquery.validate.js`... it's only the minified version.  You can use `jquery.validate.js` OR you can use `jquery.validate.min.js` as they contain identical code.  See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: I know they contain identical code, I happen to know what a minified version of a file is :)  I wrote it was it's child only because it appears so in the visual studio. This however doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It's not supposed to answer your question... that's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: You'll get more eyes on this using a more popular or generic tag, so I added [tag:asp.net] and [tag:visual-studio].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the above offered solutions worked for me.

The problem was solved by smart people at Microsoft with a VS update or by those working on open source stuff.

Must have been a bug or something.

Anyway, thanks for the help guys..

Comment: I seriously don't understand why my answer got down-voted. It would be really nice of those people who down-voted it if they could explain what they didn't like about my answer..

Comment: It is down voted because it is lacking any useful information. At least try to add which update solved it ...

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer - I don't know which update fixed it. I honestly don't have a clue how it got fixed. Maybe I should have been dishonest and I should have accepted one of the other guys' answers above...come to think of it, I can still delete my answer and do that...

Comment: That sounds like a better idea. You can always leave a comment as well, stating it resolved it self on the answer you accept.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the Grunt file which will build the dist folder for you. The best way I've found to do this right now is to install the [Grunt Launcher extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcbc5325-79ef-4b72-960e-0a51ee33a0ff). You can then right click on the package.json file within the jQuery-validation folder and select "NPM Install". That should build the dist folder for you.

I haven't found a way to automate this yet, but I'm sure there is. Just started using Gulp and wasn't using Grunt until I ran into the problem you're having. If someone has some tips there, that would be great. Good luck!

Comment: I finally achieved to instal Grunt and let it build the dist folder. Happy dancing until I compiled my app and I got this error:  MSB4018 The "FindConfigFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters. The folder path is +- 115 chars long (D:\Gebruiker\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ToolsApp\src\UI\wwwroot\lib\jquery-validation\dist\localization) What am I doing wrong|?

Comment: I found forcing Bower in VS2017RC to use jquery-validation version 1.15.0 (not 1.16.0 which is current latest version) solved my issues as that came with the dist folder. Interestingly jquery-validation-unobtrusive 3.2.6 (current latest version) works fine with 1.15.0

Answer (score 4):

Right click on Bower.json file and select Open Command Line ==> PowerSell

[image]

type *bower update*

That's how I resolved my problem..

Comment: If I right click the Bower.json file there is no Open Command Line ==> PowerShell option...Anybody any other idea how to solve this issue

Comment: you start powershell by typing in powershell and hitting return. The answer above is using a very confusing syntax ;) also it does not work for me anyway. bower is not a PS command. There is a step missing here.

Comment: for me the entire lib folder was missing - even after building and watching the bower log messages seem like everything was working.  Opening a cmd shell to the project dir and running `bower update` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me. But yeah first you go to CMD then type POWERSHELL .. and THEN type bower update

Answer (score 1):

If **Bower** doesn't restore the correct packages:

- delete everything from the **directory** value specified in **.bowerrc** which is located into your web project folder (e.g. ***wwwroot/lib***)
- open **Git Bash** ([Git SCM for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) -> when installing, choose **Git Bash** option)
- go to your web project folder (where **bower.json** is located)
- run the following:

  ```
  bower cache clean
  bower install
  ```

  **OR**

  ```
  bower update
  ```

Below it's an **example** of **bower.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6"
  }
}
```